# Cannot get element id in javascript inside for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use getElementById() inside loop as the id of my each div I want to get is in sequence like total_comments1, total_comments2, total_comments3,.. and so on. This ids are assigned by output using php.

Here is my code to display my div:

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret) ):
        $i++;
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="col3 col">
                <div id="<?php echo "total_comments".$i ?>"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    for(var i in (result.response)) {
        var a=document.getElementById("total_comments" + i );
        a.innerHTML = result.response[i].posts;
    }
</script>
```

When I use only *"total_posts"* in document.getElementBy ID it does not give any error. But when I use *"total_posts"+i* it gives error on next line. *Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*

Comment: can you check the generated html to see what is are id attribute values

Comment: also see the value of `i` in the loop

Comment: Yes, I have checked the id attribute values of div. They as I have mentioned above total_comments1, total_comments2,...

Comment: What is `result.response`

Comment: I did checked value of i by console.log() and it is like 0,1,2,3,..

Comment: I'm guessing you are out of line with your loops, one starting at 0, the other starting at 0 but you immediately jump it to 1 - try this `var a=document.getElementById("total_comments" + (i+1) );`

Comment: result.response is array i am receiving as a response from my ajax request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array have starting index from `0`.

In your case, you are incrementing `$i` before assigning.

That is causing your ids start from `1` not `0`

You should increment it after assigning.

**Corrected code:**

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret)):
?>
 <tr>
  <td class="col3 col">
   <div id="<?php echo "total_comments".$i ?>"></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
<?php
 $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: You please read my php code again. I have initialized $i to 0 then at starting of loop I am incrementing it.

Comment: @NiraliAcharya, I have given you an approach to solve your question. It does not mean, it is perfect or you must follow it. It was just my observation. You can continue with your own code.

Comment: Sorry for that. But you see above I am incrementing variable i at loop starting.

Comment: @NiraliAcharya, as per my little knowledge, that is the issue. If you view source of your HTML, you can easily find it out.

Comment: This is my html output: <td class="col3 col"><div id="total_comments1"></td></div>

Comment: Thanks and Once again sorry

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on your php cycle, try to change it like this:

```
<?php
  $i=0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret) {
    echo '<tr><td class="col3 col">'
      .'<div id="total_comments'.$i.'"></div>'
      .'</td></tr>';
    $i++;
  }
?>
```